# Android : Capture return key TextInput react native

Tags: android, react-native

I have tried using onKeyPress but it does not seem to work. How do I capture a return key from the keyboard?

```
<TextInput
    placeholder="Type.."
    style={styles.inputStyle}
    onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress}
    value={this.state.text}
 />
```

Comment: `onKeyPress` is ios-only for now. Your best bet is `onSubmitEditing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use onSubmitEditing prop and give a callback function.